# How to parse object1 which contains array1, array1 contains object2, object2 contains array3 and so on.. in typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a json response like below. I want to fetch id(s) from all levels of children so that I can put them into an array and further passed on checkbox tree.

```
   {
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "status_code": "200",
  "message": "Orgnization Hierarchy",
  "responseBody": {
    "data": {
      "id": "2",
      "parentId": "0",
      "value": "Company1",
      "children": [
        // this is level 1 object 1 
        {
          "id": "54",
          "parentId": "2",
          "value": "MasterCard",
          "children": [
            // this is level 2 of object 1
            {
              "id": "56",
              "parentId": "54",
              "value": "Branch bangalore",
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "51",
                  "parentId": "56",
                  "value": "Area1",
                  "children": [
                     { id:"66", 
                      "parentId":"56", 
                       value: "Deposite dept.",
                       // this is level 3 of object 1 and so on..
                       "children": [...] // further expanded
                     }
                   ] 
                },
                // this is level 1 of object 2
                {
                   "id": "5",
                   "parentId": "54",
                   "value": "Branch pune",
                   "children": [...]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
       // level 1 object 2
        {
          "id": "74",
          "parentId": "2",
          "value": "Axis bank",
          "children": [...] // further expanded
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, if I want to get id [in the example above like (2, 54, 56, 51, 66,...,5,...,74 )] from every level of the children, how can we achieve that? is there any recursive way or without recursive we can achieve it?

I processed below approach :

```
   var arrayOfids;
   function parsejson(){
   
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      var objectid = data[i].id
      var objchildren = data[i].children;
      getidfromchildren(objchildren);
    }
   }

   function getidfromchildren(arr){
     for(var j=0; j < arr.length; j++){
       arrayOfids.push(arr[i].id);
         
         if(arr[i].children.length != 0){
            getidfromchildren(arr);
         }
     }
   }
```

Comment: yes there is a recursive way and its actually really simple. have you tried it out yet?

Comment: Not yet because I am new to json and javascript and working on some other person's code.

Comment: Why don't you ask them then?

Comment: Not in contact. they left firm. And I m not in same firm.

Comment: Btw I edited my question and added my approach of work.

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? If yes, please share where you are stuck, and what you've tried to make it work

Comment: I want to fetch id's from all levels from above json and I want to build checkbox tree like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview/v/6.0.2 using above json structure but not able to convert it as ngx-treeview only accepts data in their formats. So, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and get all `id`.

This approach assumes, that all `children` properties have at least an empty array.

If not, you need an array as [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), like

```
getId = ({ id, children = [] }) => [id, ...children.flatMap(getId)]
//                      ^^^^
```

```js
const
    getId = ({ id, children }) => [id, ...children.flatMap(getId)],
    data = { status: "SUCCESS", status_code: "200", message: "Orgnization Hierarchy", responseBody: { data: { id: "2", parentId: "0", value: "Company1", children: [{ id: "54", parentId: "2", value: "MasterCard", children: [{ id: "56", parentId: "54", value: "Branch bangalore", children: [{ id: "51", parentId: "56", value: "Area1", children: [{ id: "66", parentId: "56", value: "Deposite dept.", children: [] }] }, { id: "5", parentId: "54", value: "Branch pune", children: [] }] }] }, { id: "74", parentId: "2", value: "Axis bank", children: [] }] } } },
    ids = [data.responseBody.data].flatMap(getId);

console.log(ids)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina. works well in javascript but in typescript there is an error in ids = [data.responseBody.data].flatMap(getId); about (error TS2339: Property 'flatmap' does not exist on type 'any[]'.)